# Different rewritten dynamic slugs seen as duplicate

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks, taxonomy, slug

I'm sorry if the post title is not too understandable...

I have a **custom post type** called `houses` and I rewrite *dynamically* the slug depending on the **taxonomy term**. The taxonomy is called `sizes` and the  **terms** are `big` and `small`.

When I create 2 posts with *same title*, the output of the slugs is like this even though the rewrite function makes it to be different slugs:

- houses/big/red-house
- houses/small/red-house-2

I even attempted to change manually the slug on the edit option but it does not let me, it still leaves the `-2` at the end of the slug. The same goes for the database, it redirects to the first post....

I don't understand why wordpress sees them as same slug... is not identifying the rewrite?

Here how I created the **custom post type**:

```
$labels = array(
        'name'              => 'Houses',
        'singular_name'     => 'House',
        'menu_name'         => 'Houses',
        'search_items'      => 'Houses'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'public'                => true,        
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-admin-home',
        'supports'              => array('title', 'editor'),
        'taxonomies'            => array('sizes', 'post_tag'), // Term & Tag
        'has_archive'           => false,
        'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'houses/%sizes%'),
        'query_var'             => true
    );
    register_post_type('houses', $args);
```

Here is my **taxonomy** code:

```
$labels = array(
        'name'              => 'Sizes',
        'singular_name'     => 'Size',
        'menu_name'         => 'Sizes',
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'            => $labels, // display name
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'public'            => true,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_in_rest'      => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'with_front'        => true
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'sizes', 'houses', $args); // Slug, CPT, array
```

And this is the code I'm using to **dynamically change the slugs**:

```
function houses_link( $post_link, $id = 0 )
{
    $post = get_post($id);

    if ( is_object( $post ) )
    {
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'houses' );

        if( $terms )
        {
            return str_replace( '%sizes%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
        }
    }
    return $post_link;  
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'houses_link', 1, 3 );
```

I hope that my explanation was clear :') thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually, this is a good question. Wordpress sees "red house" twice under `houses` post type, therefore it won't accept two posts with the same title and slug. The rewrite rule doesn't fire while you're trying to create a new post, therefore, it has no effect at that moment of generating post slugs. However, there is a way to manipulate the slug anyway you want. For example, you could add one of your taxonomies slug instead of  an incremented numbers to the end of your post title

Comment: @Ruvee Thank you so much for your help! Yes I would like to remove the `-2` or any other number after the slug and, sadly, I can't add anything more to the slug... It has to end in `red-house` in both cases :( I don't know if it can be possible that wordpress rewrites the slug at the same time of creating the post? or a way to update or flush the permalinks? I already tried `Settings>Permalinks>Save`

Comment: Can't tell you off the top of my head. I'll work on it and let you know if i were able to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

First we need to explain a little bit about how rewrite_rules and page url generation in Wordpress works

Here is the simplest url

> https://example.com/?p=1

When you go to it, Wordpress searches for a post with ID = 1 and outputs a page. And if it doesn't find it, it returns a 404.

Now a bit more complicated url

> https://example.com/?name=hello-world

Instead of ID we have a slug in the url, so Wordpress works like with the first one, it looks for this slug in the database and gives us the page.

Now let's look at the url of this page with permalinks enabled

> https://example.com/hello-world/

What happens when Wordpress sees such a url?
It goes to its rewrite_rules list to see if there is a regex for that url.

With regex we extract key data from the url and send a request to the standard url

> ```
> https://example.com/?name=hello-world
> ```

Now let's have a look at your URLs

> https://example.com/houses/big/red-house

When Wordpress sees this url, it finds the appropriate regex for it in the list of rewrite_rules, extracts the 'red-house' slug, and then sends a request to

> https://example.com/?houses=red-house

And that's why when creating a post in Wordpress there are checks to make sure the slug is unique to the post_type
Because with these links

> https://example.com/houses/small/red-house

> https://example.com/houses/medium/red-house

> https://example.com/houses/giga/red-house

Wordpress will do the same thing as the first link, it will send the request to

> https://example.com/?houses=red-house.

Wordpress has no requests with slug+term for single pages, only slug.

What should we do to solve this problem?

It doesn't have to be a one-piece slug, we can assemble it from different parts of the url

What we need to do:

1. Add custom_field 'house_base_slug', because after post_type_link the slug will no longer be editable.
2. Make a function that will create a single unique 'TermSlug-and-house_base_slug' format slug from our custom_field and term slug

> ```
> add_action( 'save_post_houses', 'house_save_new_slug' );
> function house_save_new_slug($post_id) {
>     
>         //disable
>         remove_action( 'save_post_houses', 'house_save_new_slug' );
>
>         $house_base_slug = get_post_meta($post_id, "house_base_slug", true);
>         if($house_base_slug =='') {
>         $house_base_slug = $post_id;
>         }
>         $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, 'sizes' );
>         
>         $term_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
>         if($term_slug == "") {
>         $term_slug = 'default';    
>         }
>         $new_house_slug = $term_slug . '-and-' .  $house_base_slug;
>         // update the post. At this time the save_post hook is triggered
>         wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => $post_id, 'post_name' => $new_house_slug ) );
>         clean_post_cache( $post_id );
>         // Enable
>         add_action( 'save_post_houses', 'house_save_new_slug' );
> }
> ```

There is 1 important point here, we update post_name(slug) and this triggers the save_post hook
To avoid a loop, we disable our function before the update

> remove_action('save_post_houses', 'house_save_new_slug' );

And we turn it back on after

> add_action('save_post_houses', 'house_save_new_slug' );

Now when you create or update a house, a slug of this format 'TermSlug-and-house_base_slug' will be automatically created.
If our custom_field 'house_base_slug' is empty - post_id will be taken.
If there is no term - slug 'default' will be used

3. Ok, now we have a 'small-and-red-house' slug.
   We have to associate it with our url

> ```
> add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_rule_my_house' );
> function rewrite_rule_my_house(){
>   add_rewrite_rule( '^houses/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?houses=$matches[1]-and-$matches[2]', 'top' );
> }
> ```

Don't forget to disable/enable permalinks after this step, we need to reset the cache.

3. Updating permalinks

> ```
> function custom_post_permalink( $permalink, $post, $leavename, $sample ) 
> {
>     if ( $post->post_type == 'houses'  ) {
>
>       $post_name = $post->post_name;
>       $post_name_exploded = explode('-and-', $post_name);
>       $current_slug_part1 = $post_name_exploded[0];
>       $current_slug_part2= $post_name_exploded[1];
>       $post_cur_id = $post->ID;
>       
>
>       
>       $slug = '/houses/' . $current_slug_part1 .'/' . $current_slug_part2 . '/';
>
>       
>       $permalink = home_url($slug, 'https');
>     }
>     return $permalink;  
> }
> add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'custom_post_permalink', 10, 4 );
> ```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, thank you so much for helping! I deleted the part that _dynamically changes the slugs_ and added yours. Some errors regarding undefined values appeared when wanting to create a new post :( luckily, I could still input info. After creating the post, the url was not correct. It outputted like this `houses/small/77` (using the id) until I hit the update button it outputted how it should `houses/small/red-house` . The slug was as I needed to but now when I click the link, it takes me to a 404 page... I cleaned the permalinks but still nothing appears :( As always thanks!

Comment: You add new add_rewrite_rule to functions.php ?

Comment: I checked one more time, code working on my demo wordpress. If is still dont work on your wp - make a full screenshot of the house page and the list of houses from the admin panel and post the links here